# Finding the random x-values used by geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to be able to select observations from a box plot with jittered points over top. I have been somewhat successful by having the point click find the category, look at the y-value and select the observation.  The following code shows my progress so far:

```
# ------------------------------Load Libraries---------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# -------------------------Print Boxplot to Screen-----------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput('irisPlot', click = 'irisClick'))

server <- function(input, output){

# --------------------------Store Clicked Points-------------------------------  

  clicked <- reactiveValues(rows = rep(TRUE,nrow(iris)))

# ---------------------------Modify the Dataset--------------------------------  

  IRIS <- reactive({iris %>% mutate(index = clicked$rows)})

# ---------------------Select Points Through Plot Click------------------------  

  observeEvent(
    input$irisClick,{
      nS <- iris %>% mutate(selected = rep(FALSE,nrow(iris)))  
      lvls <- levels(iris$Species)
      plant <- lvls[round(input$irisClick$x)]
      pxl <- which(
        sqrt((iris$Sepal.Width-input$irisClick$y)^2) %in%
        min(sqrt((iris$Sepal.Width-input$irisClick$y)^2)) 
      )
      point <- iris[pxl,'Sepal.Width']
      nS[nS$Species == plant & nS$Sepal.Width %in% point,'selected'] <- TRUE
      clicked$rows <- xor(clicked$rows, nS$selected)
    })

# --------------------------Generate the Boxplot-------------------------------  

  output$irisPlot <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(1)
    ggplot(IRIS(), aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width))+
      geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE,outlier.shape = NA)+
      geom_jitter(
        na.rm = TRUE,
        width = .8,
        aes(shape = index, size = index, colour = index)
      )+
      theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = NA),
        legend.position = "none"
      )+
      scale_shape_manual(values = c('FALSE'= 1,'TRUE'= 19))+
      scale_size_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 4, 'TRUE'= 2))+
      scale_colour_manual(values = c('TRUE' = "#428BCA", 'FALSE' = '#FAA634'))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As I said the code mostly works but it can be inconsistent. Sometimes it can't find a point, other times it selects a large group of points or selects a point on the opposite side of the box plot.  I figure the best way to solve this is to have both an x and y coordinate to select the point however, since the x values are randomly generated I need geom_jitter() to tell me what x-values it is using for a given plot but I have not been able to find any way to access this. Any help finding this information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could pull out the dataset used for plotting via `layer_data`?  If you named your plot `g1`, it would look something like `layer_data(g1, i = 2)`.

Comment: Rather than try to get the x coordinates out of geom_jitter, I'd suggest making them yourself before the plotting part of the pipeline and using geom_point.  That is, do the jittering yourself as the very first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thanks to aosmith for telling me about the layer_data() function and to Peter Ellis for suggesting that I use geom_point() instead of geom_jitter() both comments were instrumental in helping me solve my problem.

What I had to do was create a new plot object in the global environment to jitter the points. Then use the layer_data() function to return the newly created x-values.

Finally, using those x-values, I created a new plot object and layered the points over top using geom_point(). Here is the completed code for anyone interested.

```
# ------------------------------Load Libraries---------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# ----------------------------Generate X Coords--------------------------------

set.seed(1)
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width))+
  geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE,outlier.shape = NA)+
  geom_jitter(na.rm = TRUE,width = .8)
xPoints <- layer_data(g1, i = 2)$x

# -------------------------Print Boxplot to Screen-----------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput('irisPlot', click = 'irisClick')
)

server <- function(input, output){

# --------------------------Store Clicked Points-------------------------------  

  clicked <- reactiveValues(rows = rep(TRUE,nrow(iris)))
  rand <- reactiveValues(x = rep(NA,nrow(iris)))

# ---------------------------Modify the Dataset--------------------------------  

  IRIS <- reactive({iris %>% mutate(index = clicked$rows)})

# ---------------------Select Points Through Plot Click------------------------  

  observeEvent(
    input$irisClick,{
      nS <-data.frame( iris,  x = xPoints)
      point <- nearPoints(
        df = nS,
        coordinfo = input$irisClick,
        xvar = 'x',
        yvar = 'Sepal.Width',
        allRows = TRUE
      )
      clicked$rows <- xor(clicked$rows, point$selected_)
    })

# --------------------------Generate the Boxplot-------------------------------  

  output$irisPlot <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(IRIS(), aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width))+
      geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE,outlier.shape = NA)+
      geom_point(
        aes(
          x = xPoints,
          y = iris$Sepal.Width,
          shape = index,
          size = index,
          colour = index 
        ),
        inherit.aes = FALSE
      )+
      theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = NA),
        legend.position = "none"
      )+
      scale_shape_manual(values = c('FALSE'= 1,'TRUE'= 19))+
      scale_size_manual(values = c('FALSE' = 4, 'TRUE'= 2))+
      scale_colour_manual(values = c('TRUE' = "#428BCA", 'FALSE' = '#FAA634'))
  })
  output$x <- renderPlot({

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of people like me who might be googling this problem I solved it very easily using Peter Ellis's suggestion of jittering the points myself using jitter().

I'm making it into an answer because I thought it should be more visible, I nearly missed it when I was looking at this page.